# How to make greater space between tabs in top navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I am finding it hard to, first of all, separate the tabs and then to do so evenly across the panel in the top navigation bar.
As you can see I have resorted to using the `&nbsp` entity which in my opinion is a poor solution.

```css
h1 {
    color:#D68910;
    font-family:'verdana'; 
    margin:25px;
    margin-top:25px;
}

h6 {
    color: #FFC300;
    font-family:'verdana'; 
    margin: 38px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.header {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    background-color: #454545;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-family:'verdana';
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-right: 40px;


    margin: 25px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: gray;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #454545;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    display: block;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #D68910;
}

p {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>My Name</title>
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
<h1>My Name</h1>
<h6>Bioinformatician</h6>
</div>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<li><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="#news" style="text-decoration:none">Blog&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">About me&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" style="text-decoration:none">Contact&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
</div>


<body> </body>
```

Comment: Please ask question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is use the justifiy alignment. I've removed the float, to use display:inline-block and added an :after pseudo element to cause a second line in the nav (invisible) required for the justify to kick in.

```css
h1 {
    color:#D68910;
    font-family:'verdana'; 
    margin:25px;
    margin-top:25px;
}

h6 {
    color: #FFC300;
    font-family:'verdana'; 
    margin: 38px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.header {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    background-color: #454545;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-family:'verdana';
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin: 25px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:justify;
    font-size:0;
}
.topnav:after{
content:" ";
width:100%;
height:0;
display:inline-block;
line-height:0;
}

.topnav li {
    display:inline-block;
        font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a {
color: gray;
}
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #454545;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    display: block;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #D68910;
}

p {

}
```

```html
<title>My Name</title>
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
<h1>My Name</h1>
<h6>Bioinformatician</h6>
</div>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<li><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news" style="text-decoration:none">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">About me</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```